# CSS hovering on elements

Tags: css, html

I have two div's

```
<div id="a">A</div>
<div id="b">B</div>
```

I am trying to make an effect that when hovering on `#b` the background color of `#a` changes.
I used

CSS

```
#b:hover + #a{
    background: #000;
}
```

But it is not working.
If i use

CSS

```
#a:hover + #b{
    background: #000;
}
```

It works. Hovering on `#a` changes `#b` background color.
But I need first to work.

How to make the first one work. Why is this not working?

Comment: CSS has no "preceding sibling" selector of any kind.  You're SOL unless you can use JavaScript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` and `~` combinators will target siblings *after* the left-hand selector, so what you're trying to do in your first example is not possible with pure CSS. If `#b` preceded `#a` in your markup, then it would work.

Answer (score 2):

Try using jQuery:

```
$("b").hover(function(){ /*hovering*/
    $("#a").css("backgroud-color", "#000");
}, function(){ /*hovering out*/
    $("#a").css("backgroud-color", "set_it_back_to_the_orignial");
});
```

If you want to do it with CSS then its not possible until you change your markup and get `#a` under `#b`.

Comment: @Harikrishnan you cannot do that with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work because its meaning is different.

Select element which has id a, if it directly follows as a sibling of #b. which is not in this case.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for this.

Comment: I mean to delete this answer and make it a comment!